# undefined: не могу установить значение атрибута

Tags: javascript, jquery

В зависимости от страницы, на которой находится пользователь, ему должна показываться форма с датой. При условии `c:if test="${listName != 'TODAY' and listName != 'TOMORROW'}"`, дата должна устанавливать, допустим на сегодняшний день, что и делает скрипт. Однако скрпит отрабатывает только тогда, когда условия отсутствует.

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var today = new Date();
      var day = today.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + today.getDate() : today.getDate();
      var month = today.getMonth()+1 < 10 ? '0' + (today.getMonth()+1) : (today.getMonth()+1);
      var date = day + '.' + month + '.' + today.getFullYear();
      $('#dateNow').val(date);
      alert($('#dateNow').val());
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<c:if test="${listName != 'TODAY' and listName != 'TOMORROW'}">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="dateNow">date:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-9">
        <input id="dateNow" name="dateTask" required placeholder="date"/>
      </div>
    </div>
</c:if>
```

Comment: смотри, если у тебя не выполняется условие `<c:if test="${listName != 'TODAY' and listName != 'TOMORROW'}">`, то данной строки `<input id="dateNow" type="date" value="" name="dateTask" required placeholder="date"/>` **НЕТ**

Comment: @Grundy, я уже это понял, Ты мне объяснил. Вопрос в том, как теперь реализовать задачу?

Comment: @ДмитрийСтеба, очевидно с текущим кодом никак, потому что ты хочешь получить и подставить значения туда, где ничего нет.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66059/discussion-on-question-by---undefined-----).

Answer (score 1):

По сути ответ мне дал в виде комментария @Grundy:
"похоже на шаблонизатор. При невыполнении условия блок внутри просто не добавляется на страницу, поэтому $('#dateNow') не найдет ни одного элемента, и вполне логично что у ничего значение тоже будет undefined". Спасибо